# Has there ever been an instance of an active nuclear power plant within or near a war zone?

Tags: war, nuclear

**The question**

Has there ever been a military combat going on around an active (running or in outage but not decommissioned) commercial nuclear power plant? Or dangerously near it? If yes, how did the plant and its personnel fare in such situation?

**Why I ask**

Let's assume for the scope of this question modern commercial nuclear power plants (CANDU, PWR, BWR of generation II plus all of gen III and newer) are usually reasonably safe to operate given that the engineering has been done right and there is a whole cohort of very well trained personnel on-site at all times, well rested and with considerable resources on their hands. Things hard to get with an armed conflict like the recent Syrian war raging around. I can't seem to find any reference or a comprehensive article about this, hence this question.

---

**Edit to clarify**

Alex asks *how far is near*: as far or near as it gets for the plant operations to be affected. For example, if there was front a thousand kilometers away but all operators were drafted into military forces, the power plat would be affected. On the other hand, the 200 km distance in Ukraine is a point of debate under the question below, since the military action was feared to affect the Zhaporizhia Nuclear Power Plant, but in the end it didn't.

T.E.D. mentions nonoperational power plants being swept in conflict. As I'm interested in the *operations* being affected, nonoperational power plants are not considered.

LangLangC, Mike Scott and others wanted clarification on *why only commercial and not military installations*. The reasoning is that military installations are built for the purpose of a military conflict (either conducting or preventing it) and thus are built, supplied and run with an armed conflict in mind. Modern civilian nuclear power plants are built to withstand a certain level of a direct attack, but that is not what I ask about. Today we get reports on war in real time, with video and picture in high resolution, over WhatsApp, Facebook and similar, which means even under direct siege the civilian infrastructure works at least to a degree, hospitals are low on personnel and materials but still run, albeit a more basic service. Nuclear power plants are the greatest risk to populace when run without the required care, but requirements for power supply may under circumstances override standard safety requirements. at the same time, it is impossible to run "a third of a nuclear power plant", but it is difficult to predict where the line is. I'm interested in instances of civil/commercial power station operations being affected, whether there at all was such an instance, and what lessons can be learned from it for a civilian not directly involved in operations but wanting an insight and understanding.

**Second edit**

Large water reservoirs have been mentioned repeatedly, which may help define this question another bit better because there is one crucial difference between nuclear and other power generation modi and that is what I wanted to ask about (I admit I haven't worded the original question very clearly and I'm sorry about that).

You can attack a dam or a nuclear reactor with a missile or a hijacked airplane and cause considerable damage. You can even attack a high rise building and cause unprecedented damage, casualties and long term aftereffects throughout the human society. This doesn't single out the nuclear operations from other terror or military targets (and the *extent* of damage is off topic in the scope of this question).

What does single the nuclear operation out as a point of interest is the fact that a nuclear power plant can't be left without the many highly and very specifically trained personnel operating it 24/7 even when the reactor is shut down as quickly as possible without compromising its safety. Which fact makes it easy to compromise the safety of a nuclear power station with a seemingly unrelated action (e.g. confiscating all buses or simply setting up a checkpoint in the area may lead to a number of important people missing their shift which in turn may lead to overworking operators who are already stressed out by the whole situation). To the best of my knowledge this doesn't apply to other means of power generation or in broader sense infrastructure operations, or when yes, the possible consequences are not as dire as with nuclear power generation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87998/discussion-on-question-by-pavel-has-there-ever-been-an-instance-of-an-active-nuc).

Comment: You say "Nuclear power plants are the greatest risk to populace when run without the required care", but I'd invite you to consider large hydroelectric dams as well - the Tabqa dam was at risk recently in the Syrian civil war, and outside of conflict the Banqiao dam collapse killed 171,000 people.

Comment: @llama The important difference is that when in a good shape and built with sound engineering, you can shut a hydroelectric power plant pretty quickly and leave it as it is with floodgates open. you can't do that with a nuclear power station, it needs to be manned and carefully operated a long time after you shut it down to prevent environmental damage and direct safety risks to the populace. Off course you can bomb the dam, but that is not what I ask about.

Comment: @Pavel You can shut down a nuclear plant far more quickly that you can empty a vast reservoir safely. Even assuming you can at all.

Comment: @Rekesoft First, this is off topic here. Second, emptying a large reservoir of water is of no interest to me. You can leave the dam full for prolonged periods of time, given its well built. You can't leave a nuclear power plant unattended, even when shut down. As repeatedly emphasized in comments and edits, I'm interested in _operations being affected_, not about attacks, not about withstanding damage from direct hits, not about theoretical comparison to other sources of energy.

Comment: Update as of 2022-02-28:  the widely-reported capture of the Chernobyl Plant by Russian forces, while troubling, probably doesn't qualify since the plant has not produced electricity since 2000.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [Ten-Day War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-Day_War), in 1990, was Slovenia's war of independence from Yugoslavia.  During this war, at least a few battles took places within 10-20 km of the [Krško Nuclear Power Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kr%C5%A1ko_Nuclear_Power_Plant), which had been operating since 1983.  The [map from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Slovenian_war_map.jpg) shows at least three battles in the vicinity;  below, I've annotated the map with the Krško plant's location.  (Note the scale in the lower right.)

[image]

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find any online English-language sources on how (or whether) the Krško plant was affected by the fighting.  [A 2015 article](https://www.neimagazine.com/features/featurenuclear-plants-in-war-zones-4536247/) in *Nuclear Engineering International* claims that the plant remained operational during the war, but doesn't provide much more info:

> The battlefield map shows that engagement took place along the road passing a few kilometres from the plant. About 70 people were killed during the conflict. The station remained in operation and there is no information on the impact of the conflict on the plant safety or equipment, although it was clearly a stressful experience for the plant personnel.

The cited figure of 70 casualties is for the entire war, not just the nearby battles;  the Ten-Day War was neither prolonged nor intense.

Comment: Good find! The links you provided make a good starting point. And, wow, an armed conflict brushed a nuclear power plant this near, and in the middle of Europe at that, I'm surprised they kept running.

Comment: @Pavel - You likely know more than I about this, but I understand a nuclear reactor isn't something you can go unplug from the wall if there's trouble.

Comment: @Pavel, it takes a while to shut a nuclear reactor down: even after you've inserted the control rods to stop the primary reaction, you still need to keep the cooling pumps running for a week or two until the secondary decay heat dies down.  Starting a reactor back up is also a slow process.

Comment: @T.E.D. You don’t unplug it from the wall, but you can transition the high power chain reaction to something more controllable (low power state, chain reaction shut down etc) which would be, for me, a logical thing to do. At least in Europe nuclear reactors are transitioned to low power for much less scary reasons than an armed conflict virtually at the gates (for example out-of-spec vibration on the turbine, which doesn’t affect niclear safety, although it is overall bad for business).

Comment: @Mark of course it does. But look at the operationsl history: commissioned in 1983, still strugling for long term operational license in 1989, and being transitioned (to low reactor output or full outage) 70 times druring that period for various safety and operational reasons. The conflict took place in 1990. It is much better to defend or hand over a nuclear power plant in low power or in outage - business and integrity of the machine still at risk, but at much lower one than at sustained full thermal output of the reactor.

Comment: To explain - this is exactly why I asked the question, to find out how it worked out when the operators found themselves dangerously near a conflict, and it turns out in both cases (this and the Ukraine situation) kept running. The operators are usually very well versed in predictable situations leading to an unscheduled outage (e.g. keep the turbine running with this level of vibration and you ruin it) but an armed conflict is a highly unpredictable one and I’ve never seen a decision chart for such scenario as this. It’s just that I’m surprised (and motivated to find out more on this).

Comment: @Pavel I suspect part of the reason is that nobody really wants to damage the nuclear plant in a firefight. Conventional warfare is about acquiring territory and/or capital, and destroying the very things you're fighting for isn't really good strategy; and that's even before considering international political fallout. If you're the separatists responsible for destroying an NPP, UN probably isn't going to be very nice to you about your claims. *Accidental* damage is relatively unlikely, since the buildings are usually highly resilient. Fanatics like ISIS are a much bigger threat, of course.

Comment: @T.E.D. IIRC, you can (not unplug the reactor, of course, but shut it down in a matter of hours), but only if you don’t particularly plan to spin it back up later, because there’s going to be nasty stuff in the active zone that either takes a couple of weeks to decay or is just plain difficult to quantify. There’s also the question of whether this would make it any easier: sure, you don’t need to watch over the reaction anymore, but there’s still a lot of radioactive stuff lying around (including the water and the concrete) which turns everything it touches into even more radioactive stuff.

Comment: (On a related note, is a _nuclear_ power plant that bad? Or rather, is it that worse than, say, a big hydroelectric one? You can see it coming and it’ll kill you now rather than ten years later, but does that really help? I mean operational concerns, madmen notwithstanding. And I’m serious, I know next to nothing about hydroelectric plants.)

Comment: @AlexShpilkin:  The "nasty stuff in the active zone" is still decaying, and so it can still generate enough heat to cause a meltdown.  This is precisely what happened at Fukushima:  the control rods stopped the uranium from reacting, but the design required the core to be cooled for several days to dissipate the extra heat from the daughter nuclides.  Unfortunately, the cooling pumps were powered by diesel generators that had been knocked out by the tsunami.  So it's not necessarily possible to "unplug" the reactor and bug out within hours, even if you never plan to restart it.

Comment: @Luaan As a belligerent you sure don't want to blow up a nuclear reactor, but you may not want the other side have a good source of electricity, for example. The comments helped my thoughts crystallize, that's why it's not explicitly stated in the original question. I'm not interested in directly inflicted damage as much as when one or the other party to the conflict purposefully limits the operations or is pushed to because of an unforeseen or indirectly related problem elsewhere - one or two missed shift changes because of a blockade can do a great harm.

Comment: @AlexShpilkin If I'm not much mistaken, the dams built for hydroelectric power generation stations are usually built in such a way that the dam itself remains intact and working even with the power generation completely shut down (or re-engineered after an unforeseen failure, like the new spillway of the famous Sayano-Sushenskaya in Russia). With nuclear, even when your station supplies zero Watts to the network, you need a huge number of highly qualified people around the clock making sure the whole thing remains safe. That is what make them unique in my view, hence this whole question.

Comment: @Pavel Yes, but you need to weigh the benefits. There's probably plenty of e.g. coal power plants nearby that give you the same advantage (disrupting the power network) and can both be far easier and cheaper to replace afterwards. And if it comes to that, disrupting the grid itself (and railroads, and...) might be an even better choice.

Comment: @Luaan Military tactics are off topic here. I used the disruption as an example to support the middle road between blowing a nuclear power plant and leaving it completely alone (as seems to be the way it's done these days). Disrupting the grid and the railroads, on the other hand, is exactly the same I mention in my comment (as a possible cause of disruption to normal operation). But this is getting very hypothetical anyway, judging from the two valid answers, no sch disruptions have ever happened.

Answer (score 53):

Best example I know of is the [Zhaporizhia Nuclear Power Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaporizhia_Nuclear_Power_Plant). Its in Southern Ukraine, which unfortunately put it right within the area that the <s>Russians</s> "separatist rebel forces" wanted to use to carve themselves a corridor of Russian territory through Ukraine to Crimea in 2014.

I don't believe the city itself was directly attacked, but it was at one point only about 200KM from the fighting in Donesk, and some armed separatists did at one point reportedly try to take over the nuclear plant. It was [enough of a concern](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-fears-fighting-spread-zaporizhzhya/26571111.html) that the residents started calling up and arming militias, setting up checkpoints, and digging trenches to defend the city.

[image]

In case you were wondering, this plant does in fact use a different ([and safer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VVER#Safety_barriers)) reactor design than the Chernobyl plant. However, it has more reactors than a typical nuclear plant (6), which means more chances for something to go wrong in a reactor.

Comment: We differ in our interpretation of 200km but this probably is the best example.  My reading of the armed group that approached the city near the plant was something closer to civil disorder than warfare, but sources in English aren't clear.

Comment: This seems like _the_ answer to me, if nothing worse comes up. The comments are quite informative as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87962/discussion-on-answer-by-t-e-d-has-there-ever-been-an-instance-of-an-active-nucl).

Comment: You could add a source for the photo (I suspect you are not the author).

Comment: Google image search provides several links for the above image including [www.rferl.org](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-fears-fighting-spread-zaporizhzhya/26571111.html). Their caption: "Hundreds of residents of Zaporizhzhya dig a trench on September 6 in an effort to defend the city of Zaporizhzhya, whose region lies next to war-torn Donetsk."

Comment: @gerrit - I **did** add the source. Its the hyperlink in the sentence right on top of the photo. Click it, you will see the photo (and the caption tanderson reported), and a whole bunch of supporting textual material.

Comment: After much thinking about which answer to select as accepted I chose the Yugoslavian one based on the proximity of the conflict, since I haven't it would be necessary to set a criterium for acceptance when I asked the question - that alone shows the merit of your answer and it being well upvoted.

Comment: @Pavel - That's the one I would have accepted too. For the record, I voted for it as well.

Comment: The [Zaporizhye plant was shelled and captured by Russian forces](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/04/europe/ukraine-zaporizhzhia-nuclear-plant-attack-explainer-intl/index.html) in the Russian invasion of Ukraine in March 2022.  Someone should probably write up a new answer to this effect — I figure you should have first crack at it if you want, but I can do so if you're uninterested/don't have time.

Answer (score 18):

In 1981, Israel intentionally destroyed an Osiris-class research reactor. Basically, they flew in, bombed it to pieces, then flew away. While this was a just a sneak attack and not a part of protracted hostilities, it most certainly was an act of war.

[Please read more about this on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera)

Comment: It was indeed a military action, but the facility was still under construction and there are valid reasons to believe it was not even built as civilian power generation station. I'm interested in civilian nuclear power _operation_ being affected by conflict.

Comment: It was _definitely_ not a civilian (or any sort of) power generation station. You don't need 93% enriched Uranium for power generation. The claimed purpose of the reactor was for research, not nuclear power.

Comment: @reirab France (and obviously Iraq) would disagree with you. Interestingly, there are sources (including someone who [personally inspected the reactor](http://accuracy.org/release/1242-myth-israels-strike-on-iraqi-reactor-hindered-iraqi-nukes/)) which say it was not capable of generating nuclear weapons and Iraq's nuclear weapons program was borne out of the attack (same source, different person), rather than hampered by it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf No, Iraq and France both claimed the reactor was for _nuclear research_ purposes, not power generation. No one claimed that it was a power generation station, which is what this question was asking about.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Power reactors typically use [Low Enriched Uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium#Low_enriched_uranium_(LEU)), typically around 3-5% U235. The Uranium delivered for this reactor was 93% enriched, which is definitely not used for power generation. The only valid reasons for such enrichment are research, production of other radioactive isotopes, and nuclear weapons production. This is weapons-grade [Highly Enriched Uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium#Highly_enriched_uranium_(HEU)).

Comment: @reirab ["Baghdad reiterated a previous statement that the French atomic reactor was designed for research and for the eventual production of electricity."](https://fas.org/nuke/guide/iraq/facility/osiraq.htm). Just because HEU isn't generally used to generate power doesn't mean it's incapable of doing so: case in point [US naval reactors](https://www.nato.int/acad/fellow/99-01/maerli.pdf)(page 26): "use uranium enriched to at least 93%... a U.S. submarine reactor core contains an
average of 200 kg of U-235 enriched to 97.3%"

Comment: @TemporalWolf Note the next sentence, "This is material that is directly usable in nuclear weapons." There are reasons it isn't used for civilian nuclear power production: 1) It isn't needed and 2) See above quoted sentence. The document you linked is literally about the weapons proliferation dangers posed by allowing the use of such highly-enriched Uranium for power production, even in the closely-guarded military application of naval reactor fueling.

Comment: By the way, I'm not claiming Iraq was definitely using it to develop weapons. I'm just saying that it was a research reactor, not a civilian nuclear power station, and, thus, isn't what this question was asking about.

Comment: @reirab There is a whole class of reactors, [fast neutron reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-neutron_reactor#List_of_fast_reactors) which use HEU, up to and including weapons-grade. There are [real-life, currently running civilian power stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Breeder_Test_Reactor) running on weapons-grade plutonium of this design. The design is also advantageous from a nuclear waste perspective. The claim that there "[t]he only valid reasons..." is not accurate. Although I still think this answer stands, even if the OP has since clarified to exclude it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf That's an experimental reactor. OP's original question asked only about "commercial nuclear power plants." The question itself hasn't changed at all. The edit just added an explanation for why OP _wasn't_ asking about military facilities or other non-civilian-power-plant reactors, since people kept posting answers about other stuff.

Comment: @reirab Feel free to pick another of the ones from the list. It still proves the counterpoint.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I looked at the others, too. All of the production civilian power stations I saw information on aren't using weapons-grade material. At any rate, whether any such reactors exist is irrelevant to the fact that the facility mentioned in this answer wasn't a "commercial nuclear power plant," as the question asked about.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Thank you for the links, I'm a bit better informed after reading the "myth" page. Although it moves the Osirak installation a bit nearer the scope of my question as a more civilian and production oriented, it still remains disqualified as not yet active. The discussion about the level of enrichment brings up one perhaps interesting point - as with space travel or the Internet, the commercial nuclear power generation has its roots deep in the original military research and development and it carries its legacy still today, even if to a small extent.

Answer (score 15):

Dimona Nuclear Research center is not a commercial power plant but it is 50 miles from the border with Gaza, which is a permanent war zone.

Comment: I don't think I'd personally call Dimona a 'war zone.' Be'ersheva is half that distance to Gaza and I wouldn't call it a 'war zone,' either, even if the occasional Hamas terrorist launches a rocket in that direction. That said, perhaps the situation was different during one of the many wars in the region. It would be interesting to see maps of how close hostile forces actually got to Dimona during, for example, the Yom Kippur War.

Comment: @reirab:  Two MiGs (either Soviet or Egyptian, sources vary) [flew over the facility shortly before the Six-Day War,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Peres_Negev_Nuclear_Research_Center#Jet_aircraft_take-down) but I suspect the OP is more interested in ground forces.

Comment: I don't care that much about the type of military force involved, but I'm mainly interested in civilian nuclear operation. Dimona is, IIRC highly classified operation with a mainly military purpose.  I've edited the question to address the recurring question about why I'm not interested in primarily military nuclear operations.

Comment: @reirab: I did not claim that Dimona in in the war zone. And in the question it was not defined what "near" means. Anyway, it is much closer to the war Zone than the Ukrainian station in Zaporizhzhia.

Answer (score -3):

> **Q** Has there ever been an instance of an active nuclear power plant within or near a war zone?

Yes, quite a lot.

And even one *would have been* one too many. And every last one of the was *one too many.*

Directly attacked or "affected" active plants were found in Israel, Ukraine and Yugoslavia. Proving in every instance that supporting atomic power is an untenable position.

---

> **Q** The reasoning is that military installations are built for the purpose of a military conflict (either conducting or preventing it) and thus are built, supplied and run with an armed conflict in mind.

That is wishful thinking as it is prevalent in pro-atom circles of all colours. All reactors are built with "this doesn't blow up" in mind. And yet, Windscale, Three-Mile-Island, Chernobyl and Fukushima are just the most prominent examples where "shit happens" was the ansewr to "what could  *possibly go wrong?" Reactors for the military are not safer than "commercial" plants. Even if they were: why then build knowingly and on purpose less secure atomic reactors for commercial use?

It seems irrelevant to focus on "commercial" and "active" reactors, as the real criteria for damage are more likely "contains radioactive material to be spread when hit". That would include pre-operational and post-operational reactors. Whether they are commercial or strictly military or research doesn't factor in case of catastrophe facilitated by a war.

We might have to define "war zone" further: if the US wages ["war on terror"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Terror), and considered itself under attack of the homeland (ie a war zone in 2001) – would that make all its nuclear installations count? And all those in or near the countries bombed or invaded?

In centuries gone by a "war zone" might have been precisely declared. Since we now seem to prefer asymmetrical warfare, this definition is no longer that useful. Mere proximity or distance to infantry fighting on the ground was no safe haven for for example [Serbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_bombing_of_Yugoslavia), [Afghan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_(2001%E2%80%93present)),  or [Yemeni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemen_War) people.

If not, we might still look at the map of atomic [insanity](https://phys.org/news/2011-05-nuclear-power-world-energy.html) to get a stricter measurement of reactors at risk of being [targets](https://www.nae.edu/19582/Bridge/19804/19892.aspx):

> [image]
>   via Carbon Brief (https://www.carbonbrief.org/mapped-the-worlds-nuclear-power-plants)

And correlate the dates of construction and "connectedness to the grid" with the list armed conflicts

> [List of wars 1945–1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1945%E2%80%931989)
>   [List of wars 1990–2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1990%E2%80%932002)
>   [List of wars 2003–present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_2003%E2%80%93present)

This is a bit misleading, as the map above is not listing secret or formerly secret armament reactors, which all *have* to be counted in. Equally, "research reactors" can be tiny or really unnecessarily large – for real research. But it appears that regardless of size and therefore danger, facilities simply declared "for research" (like [Egypt's](https://www.nti.org/learn/countries/egypt/nuclear/), Libya's or North Korea's?) are just not listed.

For example the [Shimon Peres Negev Nuclear Research Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Peres_Negev_Nuclear_Research_Center) (aka **"Dimona"**) was used by Israel to enrich enough fission material to construct bombs. This went online between 1962–1964 and obviously – that strip of land is *awfully small* – would be a quite vulnaerable target at least as early during [1973 Arab–Israeli War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Kippur_War) (Yom Kippur).

Since then it was repeatedly attacked. Iran is supposedly targeting it constantly, but Iraq actually launched rockets in 1991 at it and Hamas does so now. ([Although](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/162099#.UKeVtYf7JjI) with low accuracy, [for now](https://web.archive.org/web/20121029075853/https://www.debka.com/article/22481/Hamas-aims-Grad-at-Dimona-reactor-%E2%80%93-payback-for-Khartoum-raid).)

The response to that was that Israel first stepped up air-defenses, a few times, and by now is said to have shut down the reactor. How the personnel reacted in all of those incidents is typically not reported. Since the plant wasn't really hit, they may have never learned of the danger when it was imminent, only later.

The same goes for India and Pakistan, at the latest in [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Pakistani_wars_and_conflicts#Indo-Pakistani_War_of_1999), as India detonated "[Smiling Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiling_Buddha)" in 1974 and Pakistan had equally enough installations to declare itself on-par with ["Chagai-I"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagai-I) in 1998.
Supporters of nuclear power are cynical enough to discount the plants as endangered, as both countries have refrained from all-out-war and now have mobile bombs as well. That is of course wrongheadedly downplaying the reach of weapons available to both sides.

As the [Korean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_War) is not offiically really "over", just being an armistice, one might just look at the surroundings of the peninsula:

> [image]

This is further complicated as internal struggles and civil wars could very easily turn a bit ugly if the plants get targeted.

As is the case with the conflicts in Ukraine, which make also some indisputably Russian reactors "near" a zone of conflict. [The Washington posts counts 15 Ukrainian reactors alone in this war zone.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2014/09/03/a-worrying-factor-in-ukraines-chaos-15-nuclear-reactors/)

> **“You need to make sure you have enough security that so bad guys don’t do what the tsunami did to Fukushima — cutting off the power and disabling the backup power to start a meltdown,” Bunn says. Most nuclear plants have so much security that terrorists look elsewhere, “at a dam or a chemical plant instead,” he says.** ([Nukes of Hazard](https://grist.org/article/nuclear-is-scary-lets-face-those-fears/))

This affected the operational situation in Ukrainian plants:

> The situation in Ukraine is very a serious concern. The country has 15 reactors operating at four nuclear power plants. Ukraine is proud of its nuclear capacity, but its new circumstances make then a cause for anxiety.
>   Three stations (South Ukraine, Rovno, and Khmelnitsky) are situated in the western side of the country and are not part of this discussion. The largest plant in Europe, Zaporozhe with its six 1000 MW VVER-1000 reactors, lies about 200 km from the combat zone.
>   Thermal energy supplies and networks in Ukraine have suffered during the war. Five large thermal power plants near Donbass now operate at reduced output and are periodically in outage due to lack of coal. A hit on the unit transformer at the Lugansk power plant resulted in a blaze which put the plant out of action, blacking out a large region. Towns and villages with a total population of about 700,000 had no power, including the major industrial centre of Lugansk.
>   Easily accessible power grids have had frequent damage. Power lines, transformers and substations have all been hit by shelling and there have been many cases of intentional damage to electrical infrastructure. **The tragic deaths of grid personnel who were shot** while inspecting and repairing equipment is a black page in the history of the Ukrainian energy industry. However, during the conflict station staff have continued to work despite the threat to life and limb and through these terrible circumstances thermal energy plants have continued to generate electricity.
>   <sub>[Kovynev, 2015](https://www.neimagazine.com/features/featurenuclear-plants-in-war-zones-4536247/)</sub>

In the age of intercontinental missiles one has to count really every single last one of nuclear reactors near a potential war zone.

In recent years, we have added rhetoric of "heroic deeds being worthwhile", from quite a few sides. The means not only big rockets or errant shells are a threat. As those plants are all at least possibly quite dirty bombs in fixed positions, a small truck driven by one mad man or madam was and still is sufficient. Motivations for such an action are handed out by the dozens nowadays.

In fact some mad men are really convinced that connecting such things to "the grid" not only means simple powerlines, but electronic communications as well. Things like [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet) make the [Vulnerability of nuclear plants to attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_of_nuclear_plants_to_attack) just so much easier, not even requiring any physical presence at all.

> [Military attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_of_nuclear_plants_to_attack#Military_attacks)
>
> Nuclear reactors become preferred targets during military conflict and, over the past three decades, have been repeatedly attacked during military air strikes, occupations, invasions and campaigns:
>
> - On 25 March 1973, before its completion, the [Atucha I Nuclear Power Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atucha_I_Nuclear_Power_Plant) in Argentina was temporarily captured by the People's Revolutionary Army who stole a FMK-3 submachine gun and three .45 caliber handguns. When they retired they had a confrontation with the police, injuring two police officers.
> - In September 1980, Iran bombed the [Al Tuwaitha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Tuwaitha) nuclear complex in Iraq, in [Operation Scorch Sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Scorch_Sword), which was a surprise IRIAF (Islamic Republic of Iran Air Force) airstrike carried out on 30 September 1980, that damaged an almost complete nuclear reactor 17 km south-east of Baghdad, Iraq.
> - In June 1981, [Operation Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera) was an Israeli air strike that completely destroyed Iraq's Osirak nuclear research facility.
> - Between 1984 and 1987, Iraq bombed Iran's [Bushehr nuclear plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushehr_Nuclear_Power_Plant) six times.
> - In 1991, the U.S. bombed three nuclear reactors and an enrichment pilot facility in Iraq.
> - In 1991, Iraq launched Scud missiles at Israel's [Dimona nuclear power plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimona_reactor).
> - In September 2007, Israel bombed a [Syrian reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Orchard) under construction.

Given the expert opinion of [Alexey Kovynev in Nuclear plants in war zones (2015)](https://www.neimagazine.com/features/featurenuclear-plants-in-war-zones-4536247/), he also lists:

> - Yugoslavia, ten-day war
> - The Iran-Iraq war
> - Bombing of nuclear reactors in Iraq
> - Destruction of reactor in Syria
> - Indo-Pakistani conflicts
> - Armenian-Azerbaijani conflict
> - Ukrainian conflict

---

If already accused of "writing an essay", I can do that as well then:

> **Q**  … modern commercial nuclear power plants (CANDU, PWR, BWR of generation II plus all of gen III and newer) are usually reasonably safe to operate…

is pro-nuke-energy misconception. "Nuclear safety" can be summarised elegantly with just a few words: there is none.

> **Q** Nuclear power plants are the greatest risk to populace when run

That is correct. Just the sentence this fragment is contained in is longer than necessary.

> **Q**  I'm interested in instances of civil/commercial power station operations being affected, whether there at all was such an instance, and **what lessons can be learned from it** for a civilian not directly involved in operations but wanting an insight and understanding.

As shown above, one should not frame a question so narrow as to be no longer really useful. (In light of political opinion comments below: or reading a question so monotheistically as: there is just this one way, my way, of interpreting a question)

Taken the theoretical dangers, the unacceptable risks involved in the technology as such with very questionable profits for a few, the most important lesson that the history of atomic power is "do not use it commercially" *at all.*

The actual examples of atomic power plants physically near a combat zone, located in, around or in the proximity of war-zones are unmanagable, for sensible and responsible people. It is a va-banque of irresponsible madness. But those decent enough to understand that would probably not start a war or build these damned things.

Coupled with longer reaching weapons and now dedicated small groups (and sometimes for pro-nukers with "irrational" motives) intent to wreaking havoc shows that building and operating atomic power plants is on the same level of "good idea" as sweetening your food and drinks with lead-acetate. Sure, the taste is convincing. The effects on clear thinking seem equally comparable.

> Despite significant reforms following past disasters, we estimate that, with 388 reactors in operation, there is a 50% chance that a Fukushima event (or more costly) occurs every 60–150 years. We also find that **the average cost of events per year is around the cost of the construction of a new plant.**
>   **This dire outlook** necessitates post-Fukushima reforms that will truly minimize extreme nuclear power risks. **Nuclear power accidents** are decreasing in frequency, but **increasing in severity.**
>   In conclusion, although the frequency of events per reactor has become less common, the relative frequency with which events cascade into “dragon king” extremes is large enough that, when multiplied by severity, **the aggregate risk to society is still very high.** To effectively reduce this risk, the possibility of Chernobyl and Fukushima sized events needs to be better anticipated and then more effectively managed.
>   <sub>[Spencer Wheatley, Benjamin K. Sovacool, Didier Sornettea: "Reassessing the safety of nuclear power", Energy Research & Social Science, Volume 15, May 2016, Pages 96–100.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214629615301067) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.erss.2015.12.026))</sub>

As this is a history site: The above analysis allows the conclusion that those plants built after Windscale, "they would be safer", that of those build after Chernobyl "they would be safer", that those built unlike "Russian sloppy type", you know, those brilliant engines of the West, like in Fukushima, "are safe". Well, then this will surely not interest you as well: [Nassim Nicholas Taleb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassim_Nicholas_Taleb): "[The Black Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Swan:_The_Impact_of_the_Highly_Improbable). The Impact of the Highly Improbable", Random House, 2007.

> <sub>[Fortune’s Brian O’Keefe asked](http://fortune.com/2011/03/24/whats-next-for-nuclear-power-nassim-nicholas-taleb/) the distinguished professor of risk engineering at NYU-Poly to help us derive some lessons from the accident at Fukushima.</sub>
>
> **This is what I call the criminal stupidity of statistical science.** These models can tell you something about normal events, but they cannot deal with unexpected, high-impact events. Some guy probably measured the risk according to a formula and said, “Well, it meets the one-in-a-million standard.” But we are incapable scientifically of measuring the risk of rare events. We tend to underestimate both the probabilities and the damage.

So, what was the question again? Scrolling back to the title… **Has there ever been a nuclear power plant within or near a war zone?** –– This answer says: yes. The other answers say: yes. And it was an incredibly stupid idea.

Comment: Comments are not the place for a debate on the merits or otherwise of nuclear power.

Comment: Yes, niceness of nuclear energy is off topic here, I almost stopped reading the answer at the _atomic insanity_. The section called _military attacks_ lists almost exclusively military installations which are a natural target for an attack, the first listed has was not operation alt the time and thus the case doesn't inform us about what problems arise while running a power station with war raging about. _armament reactors which all have to be count in_ - they don't, as is explicitly stated in the question. I'm sorry, all in all this looks more like a rant to me than an answer to the question.

Comment: *the real criteria for damage*: This isn't what the OP asked for. A sensible interpretation of the question is "was there a place where the staff could have evacuated leaving the plant to fail for lack of supervision?"

Comment: Towards the end this answer is ok. Just need to remove the subjective language.

Comment: This is a deliberate attempt to fail to answer the question, while writing an essay.

Comment: Other than the Scud attack on Dimonia, and perhaps the US strikes during the Gulf War, every one of your "military attacks" was on a non-operational reactor.  Even those parts of your answer that purport to answer the question rather than rant about nuclear power, don't answer the question.

Comment: This answer is purely anti-nuclear _spam_.

Comment: @T.Sar You made me smile. Dismiss and downvote all you like, but be aware that "purely" cannot be true, as this answer *also* contains what is in other answers here, in three cases entirely *before* they did. And as the Q already is pro-nuke-power, why be so aggressive about this analysis with just so few words for framing?

Comment: @LangLangC I'll be more precise them. This answer is _mostly here to push an agenda instead of answering the question properly, as asked_. More so, I'm happy that I made you smile!

Comment: After the "I might write an essay" edit I retract my previous comment and finally downvote this edit story for what it in reality, sadly, is - a rant, deliberately contradicting two valid answers to my question without any substance to base the contradiction on (_The actual examples of atomic power plants physically near a combat zone, located in, around or in the proximity of war-zones is [sic!] unmanagable_ yet the two leading answers describe exactly such situations with perhaps a surprising fact that in neither case the operation of a nuclear power plant has been limited).

Comment: Passages such as *""Nuclear safety" can be summarised elegantly with just a few words: there is none."* reveals that this is a strongly biased opinion-piece. Not only that but it is also factually wrong; [nuclear power is the safest form of power generation out there](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jamesconca/2012/06/10/energys-deathprint-a-price-always-paid/). So I notice an ironic piece of projection here when it starts talking about "pro-nuclear propaganda". :-)

Comment: The improbably event-Fukushima equivalence is quite distorted. The severity of the Fukushima incident was in a large part caused by the massive earthquake and tsumani removing normal means of mitigating the dangers caused by the plant. That is, a Fukushima-level incident without an accompanying tsunami would have been much less significant in cost of damage terms. It is probably better to view the tsunami as the once-every-100-year event that caused the damage, and the reactor as collateral damage for that event.

Comment: @kingledion Can agree to that for a large part. The damage from quake, tsunami *and* evacuation is a big pile of mess. But here are 2 further complications: we were told all that was factored in and therefore *practically impossible*. Probably no lie by most, but clearly incorrect. And these "tsunami-factors" are just that kind of unforeseeable incidents that a nearby war-zone might produce, not by natural disaster but man-made. Past experience with tsunamis told us repeatedly that we didn't prepare for those events properly (top: building plants on fault lines and near such coasts.)

Comment: Yes, this answer has a "point of view", but the maps alone, not to mention the other factual content make it valuable.

Comment: This answer has lots of useful information, and could even be a good answer if presented in a more neutral format. For example, the opening (non-quote) line: *"Yes, quite a lot. And even one would have been one too many."* immediately turns this into a low-quality answer, especially from a historical point of view. We're talking about history, which includes **wars** where people intentionally kill each other, and floods that have killed millions. This tone rings more along the lines of a slick political push than an dispassionate review of history. If you must, link to your blog.

Comment: @LangLangC That modern NPPa are safe to operate is not a biased assertion, it is a fact, just click at the links in comments. You got all the clarification you wanted. You were welcomed repeatedly to turn your own reservation to this question into your own question. Nobody forces you to answer this question. What you call an answer here doesn't answer the question, it is an uninformed political rant. Please stop moaning. You seem impossible to satisfy and keep attacking at hominem, just like a flat-earther, chem-trailer activist. Please stop spamming, or your "answer" will need to be flagged.